# how to get the dates in the last 24 hours from an array of dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime

These are the dates i have in this format coming from a Mysql database, where i need to dynamically get all the fields in this array that fit in the last 24 hour window of now.
the issue is that the js date comes in a different format, so i am having a hard time comparing them in a clean and efficient way.

This is the date array :

```
let userTransactions = [
{
  id: 1,
  created_at: "2022-08-18 12:15:12",
  updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
},

{
  id: 2,
  created_at: "2022-08-19 10:15:12",
  updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
},
{
  id: 3,
  created_at: "2022-08-19 16:15:12",
  updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
},
{
  id: 4,
  created_at: "2022-08-19 05:15:12",
  updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
},
{
  id: 5,
  created_at: "2022-08-19 11:15:12",
  updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
},
{
  id: 6,
  created_at: "2022-08-19 08:15:12",
  updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
},


];
```

this is the function :

```
const filterTo24Hours = (userTransactions) => {
let dayTransactions = userTransactions.filter((item) => {
  let date = new Date();

  // this if statement is written to show what i want to have achieved, this is not working 
  if (date >= item.created_at && date - 1 <= item.created_at) {
    //Do something here
    console.log(item.created_at);
  }
});
return dayTransactions;
 }
```

Comment: please paste the date array

Comment: @brk my bad i just updated

Comment: What did you try to parse the string into a Date object, and what did you try to compare those two date objects? I think you'll find plenty of answers here in SO, but if you're stuck somewhere, please explain where exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without heavy additional libraries like moment.js you can transform your dates to milliseconds to compare them. I changed your first item of array with created_at within 24 hours so it returns something.

```js
let userTransactions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    created_at: "2022-08-26 12:15:12",
    updated_at: "2022-08-26 12:15:12",
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    created_at: "2022-08-19 10:15:12",
    updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    created_at: "2022-08-19 16:15:12",
    updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    created_at: "2022-08-19 05:15:12",
    updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    created_at: "2022-08-19 11:15:12",
    updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    created_at: "2022-08-19 08:15:12",
    updated_at: "2022-08-19 12:15:12",
  },
];

const filterTo24Hours = (userTransactions) => {
  let date = (new Date()).getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  let dayTransactions = userTransactions.filter((item) => (new Date(item.created_at)).getTime() >= date);
  return dayTransactions;
}

console.log(filterTo24Hours(userTransactions));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filterTo24Hours = (userTransactions) => {
    let dayTransactions = userTransactions.filter((item) => {
        // reduce 1 day from current time
        let date = Date.now() - 86400000;
        // this if statement is written to show what i want to have achieved, this is not working
        // created date converted to UTC time by default
        if (date < new Date(item.created_at).getTime()) {
            //Do something here
            //console.log(item.created_at);
            return item
        }
    });
    return dayTransactions;
}
```

Comment: "2022-08-18 12:15:12" is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. It produces an invalid date in Safari at least.